# Basic doubt on generative models

Tags: graphical-model, generative-models

I am new to statistics and while reading Bishop's book, in the 'Generative models' part 8.1.2.

When explaining *ancestral sample*, he says:

> To do this, we start with the lowest-numbered node and draw a sample
>   from the distribution $p(x_1)$, which we call $x_1$.

I cannot follow it... what he means? I must be wrong, but, for me distributions are normal, log normal, etc... I see $p(x_1)$ as just a probability, a number. How can I draw a sample from a number?

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's common to interchangeably use $p(x)$ to denote

1. A density function of some random variable $X$
2. A density function $p$, evaluated at point $x$
3. A distribution with a density function $p$.

This kind of overloading can be kind of annoying, but it's everywhere. In this context, $p(x_1)$ is a distribution.